# NUnit: How get test failed (instead of ignored) if TestFixtureSetUp failed

Tags: nunit, teamcity

We use NUnit for unit tests and TeamCity as our CI server. After each commit all tests are executing. If some tests failed then e-mail notifications are sent.

All went well but today I noticed that many tests were ignored. Also I saw message which described the reason:

> TestFixtureSetUp failed in MyApplicationTests

I was confused why these tests were ignored but not failed. My concern is that developers think all is going well but actualy tests were not run (ignored).

**Question:** how configure NUnit to fail tests (instead of ignore) if TestFixtureSetUp failed?

Maybe we can configure TeamCity to send e-mail notifications if tests are ignored. But it is not what I want because we have some tests marked with `Ignore` attribute. So notification will be send each time and becomes useless.

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity cannot filter this event and report it differently to you. There seems to be no way of programmatically failing all the tests in a fixture from the `TestFixtureSetUp` callback.

So, in my opinion, you have no chance but closely monitoring the `Ignore`s in your build results. There seems to be no automatic way of distinguishing them from the tests you actually are ignoring.

As a side note, whenever I or my colleagues marked tests with the `Ignore` attribute (in my career) it was never temporary. Always permanent. We should use the `Ignore` flag very carefully, in my opinion.